# Problema con SweetAlert2, no muestra la variable insertada

Tags: sweetalert2

Ando aprendiendo un poquito de programación, paso por aquí para pedir una ayudita , es que no he podido con sweetalert2 no me funciona, entra al Modal, pero no ejecuta el if , o sea le doy al boton entra el sweet le doy que si, pero no inserta el dato ya lo comprobé quitando el Sweet y si eso guarda correctamente.

```
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <form asp-action="Agregar" id="frmEnviar" method="post" asp-controller="TipoUsuario">
               
         
    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"  onclick="Abrir()"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    }
    
    //ver scrips el modal lo tengo por fuera
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/generic.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        function Abrir() {
    
            mostrarModal().then(res => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    var frmEnviar = document.getElementById("frmEmviar");
                    frmEnviar.submit();
    
                }
    
            })
    
    
        }
    
 
    
    //Indico modal que se encuentra en la carpeta Scripts
    function mostrarModal(titulo = "Desea grardar los cambios?",
    texto="Deseas registrar los cambios de la base de datos") {
    return  Swal.fire({
            title: titulo,
      text: texto,
           icon: 'warning',
           showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',        confirmButtonText: 'Si!'    })
}
```

Por favor ver  (form, id, input scrips y  function mostrarModal )
y como digo le quite el sweetalert y de una guarda Pero le cambio al botón por submit para que ejecute

[image: Imagen]
En este punto le doy que si pero no pasa al if

y regresa a este punto
[image: imagen]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un pequeño error, de seguro tarde o temprano lo vas a encontrar.
La variable que declaras para recibir el resultado de la Promise de la función mostrarModal se llama 'res', pero la que usas en la condicional es 'result'.

Prueba de esta forma

```
        mostrarModal().then(result => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                var frmEnviar = document.getElementById("frmEmviar");
                frmEnviar.submit();

            }

        })
```